# Magento 2: Multiple Observer Affects Speed?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom, performance, multiple

In My custom module, I have created 10 Observer Events. Which affects while clicking on "Add To Cart", "Check Out".

At single level user & development level, it's fine. My worry is when site gonna live. Have more than 2K SKU's.

Is it gonna affect performance? Because in general, I'm putting Blocks in Magento Simple Checkout Process, to achieve functionality.

Following standard procedure to create observers.

Comment: @Rakesh It's not related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the observers are doing. The framework overhead of just calling them is negligible.